# How is the viewport tag supposed to work?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the viewport width of my chrome browser in windows 7. I also want to change the zooming scale using `initial-scale`. I used the following code but nothing happens,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=400px", initial-scale=5.0">
<style>
.box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding:10px;
  border: 2px dotted black;
  background-color: cyan;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box">
Hello World
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried to alter the width as `device-width`, 50%, 50em etc but the viewport ain't changing. I also gave different values to `initial-scale` but nothing is happening.

What am I missing?

Comment: Viewport is for mobile browsers. You won't see the changes on a desktop/laptop PC. Try looking at the same page on your phone or tablet and you'll see how viewport is working.

Comment: @ThisClark I see. I found a way to emulate phone in goggle chrome using _inspect element_,.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

also change css to

```
.box {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 2px dotted black;
        background-color: cyan;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
```

you can use this web site to test in any device
http://responsivetest.net/#u=http://www.zootemplate.com|1024|768|1

Comment: What is the benefit of adding `height: auto`?

Comment: It's make the height is responsive

Comment: [But `height: auto` is default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/height); we don't need to explicitly mention this. Also could you answer my question why the viewport is not resized in windows 7.

Comment: Really i don't know it works for me in windows 10 , this example can help http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Comment: w3school is the reason I am asking questions on stackoverflow.